# RTC and Time Library Problems

Tags: arduino-uno, time, rtc

Want to use Arduino Time library and occasionally sync it with an external RTC (Maxim DS3231 chip).   I am turning LEDs on and off based on time and using a shift register (Nexperia 74HC154PW) and encoder (ST Micro STP16CPS05TTR).

It has all been working fine, until I decided to use libraries as shown in:

[https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/DS1307RTC/commit/160fa0dbca29f6fb3c1465954f89ad7f1f0fbf67](https:////https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/DS1307RTC/commit/160fa0dbca29f6fb3c1465954f89ad7f1f0fbf67%20//using%20libraries%20shown%20in%20examples/SetTime)

//using libraries shown in examples/SetTime

What I cannot figure out is why using #include <DS1307RTC.h>  prevents the LEDs from lighting.

I have only included code below that lights the LED via a shift register to demonstrate that it runs without an error, but (have to take my word) does not light the LEDs.

**If I comment out #include <DS1307RTC.h>  the LEDs light.**

Note that in the code below time is not used for anything.

What is including  <DS1307RTC.h>  doing to break it?

Puzzled.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <DS1307RTC.h>    //the problem:  Will not light LEDs if this is used

                          //RTC used is Maxim DS323`chip  
                          //RTC connected to ATMEGA328 pin 27 PC4(ADC4/SDA) and pin 28 (PC5 (ADC5/SCL)
                          //RTC works great.

//Ouputs from Atemga and Inputs into 74HC154 pins 
const int A0_Pin = 4; // Atmega328 pin  2 = Arduino pin 4 
const int A1_Pin = 5; // Atmega328 pin  9 = Arduino pin 5
const int A2_Pin = 2; // Atmega328 pin 32 = Arduino pin 2 
const int A3_Pin = 3; // Atmega328 pin  1 = Arduino pin 3

// Shift Register STP16CPS05 has 16 outputs.  Send two sets of 8 bits to turn on columns.  1 = on.
const int latchPin = 9;   // Aruino Pin 9 = ATMEGA328 DIP Pin15 = TQFP Pin 13. Connected to LE-DM1 of STP16CPS05 pin 4  Latch Pin
const int clockPin = 13;  // Arduino Pin 13 =  ATMEGA328 DIP Pin19 = TQFP 17. Connected to CLK of STP16CPS05 pin 3  Clock Pin
const int dataPin = 17;   // Arduino Pin17 = ATMEGA328 DIP Pin 26 = TQFD 26. Connected to SDI of   STP16CPS05 pin 2  Data Pin (SDI)


void setup() {

pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);    
pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);

pinMode(A0_Pin, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(A1_Pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(A2_Pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(A3_Pin, OUTPUT);
 }


void loop() {
 
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);  //LOW through inverter = HIGH = OEDisabled for both Decoder and Shift Reg
                               //LOW Shift Reg New Data to Buffer
  digitalWrite(A0_Pin, 0);
  digitalWrite(A1_Pin, 1); 
  digitalWrite(A2_Pin, 1); 
  digitalWrite(A3_Pin, 0);

  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, B11000000);
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, B11111111);

  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);  //HIGH through inverter = LOW = OE Enabled for both Decoder and Shift Reg
                               //HIGH Shift Reg Move data to Output pins 

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115773/discussion-on-question-by-rickh-rtc-and-time-library-problems).